# Minkowski-like integral inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f\colon\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be non-negative. Under which hypotheses does the following inequality hold

$$
\left\{ \int \left[ \int f(x,y)\; \mathrm{d}\mu(y) \right]^p \mathrm{d}\mu(x) \right\}^{1/p} \leq \int \left[ \int f^p(x,y)\; \mathrm{d}\mu(x) \right]^{1/p} 
\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$

?

I can easily see that (for example) $f$ should be measurable and $\int f(x,y)\; \mathrm{d}\mu(y)$ should be $L^p$ wrt $x$, what else?

Answer (score 0):

What is required is for $f \ge 0$ to be measurable with respect to the product measure $\mu \times \mu$. All of the integrals make sense even if their values are infinite.

Comment: But does the inequality always hold, or only sometimes?